# Run remote command with putty

Tags: putty

When I do `putty -ssh user@host -pw password echo "hi"`

I get a network error

But if I do `putty -ssh user@host -pw password`

An SSH session is successfully opened in a putty terminal. However, I just want to run a single command. How do I do this in Putty?

Comment: You are trying to do things which are easier to accomplish on non-Windows operating systems. Consider whether you can use something other than Windows as your workstation OS.

Comment: Why do you want to use putty like this? It is much easier to use the terminal (both in linux and osx) to do this

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's for an automated script that would be running on developer's window machines.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might want to use `plink` (which is shipped with putty) instead of putty for this.

Quote from the [documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink):

> Plink is a command-line connection tool similar to UNIX `ssh'. It is
>          mostly used for automated operations, such as making CVS access a
>          repository on a remote server.

For your example:

```
plink -ssh user@host -pw password echo "hi"
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the putty [manual](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/puttydoc.txt), there is only `-m` which can be used to give it a file containing one or more commands to be executed in sequence.

Comment: `-m` does not execute a script. It reads a list of commands to execute remotely from a local file. This might be equivalent with simple scripts that only execute command after command, but when you add loops or operations on the output of commands this will stop working. Quote from [the documention](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#S3.8.3.6): `With some servers [...] you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers.`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider `script: computing: an automated series of instructions carried out in a specific order.` But yes... it's probably clearer to say _multiple commands in sequence_

Answer (score 3):

As @GeraldSchneider suggests, PLINK is more suitable, but if you really wanted to use PuTTY this is how you could do it:

First, you need to set a few things up as follows:

1. Connect to the remote box via PuTTY, as in your example.
2. While on the remote box, create a script to echo "hi". Name it `hello.sh`.
3. Right-click the PuTTY window caption and select 'Change Settings...".
4. Type the name `my-saved-session` and click Save then Cancel.
5. Exit the session. Open the PuTTY Configuration panel again.
6. Select your saved `my-saved-session` session and click Load.
7. On the left of the 'Category' tree view, click 'SSH'.
8. In the 'Remote command' box type `~/hello.sh -o`.
9. Click back on 'Session' and click Save.

Now you're good to run the command:

`putty -ssh user@host -pw password -load my-saved-session`

Comment: item 8: maybe _~/hello.sh -o_ instead of _/hello.sh -o_  : Need to check where hello.sh was saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `pterm` (which usually ships with `putty`) **AND** you have a local `ssh` command line program, you can do the following

```
pterm -e "ssh [user]@[host] /path/to/your/program"
```

where `/path/to/your/program` could also be `bash -c "some; shell; code"`